Reflectivity layer with leaflet
I need to show the reflectivity generated by the WRF 4.6.1 forecast as a layer over a map, I use leaflet (withphp) to show the forecast in some locations but I need to generate a layer that shows the reflectivity over the domain in which the WRF makes the forecast. I saw that openweathermap.org has weather maps, I would like to know if I can do something similar and what tools you recommend I use to do it. With weather maps 1.0 I don't know if I can use my data, what I don't like is how it shows the legends and I don't know if I can modify them or not, I would like to show the wind layer with arrows and it shows them like the temperature. I would like to animate that layer (reflectivity, or all of them if possible) over time, every 3 hours or 6 hours.
Please, help me?
